# Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= dt9.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();

    ch = Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()); <--- ERROR
    ch.Checked = true;
    ch.Enabled = false;
    ch.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
}
```

I want to check seat availability of  my system, so user can check selecting show time, so user selected show time system check for available seat from database and disable `CheckBox` that are booked by other users.

So my problem is I'm getting Error on `ch = Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.FindControl` returns `Control` and you are trying to implicitly cast that to a `CheckBox`. You either need to explicitly cast it to a `CheckBox`:

```
ch = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

Or better yet cast with `as` and use a `null` check:

```
ch = Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()) as CheckBox;
if (ch == null)
{
    //The control is not a checkbox, handle it here
}
```

---

Side note: You instantiate `ch` to a `new CheckBox` and then immediately change it to the one brought back by `FindControl`. No need to do that, just do:

```
CheckBox ch = Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()) as CheckBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

just type cast to checkbox as below:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= dt9.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();

    ch =  (CheckBox)Page.FindControl(dt9.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()); <--- ERROR
if (ch != null)
{
    ch.Checked = true;
    ch.Enabled = false;
    ch.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
}
}
```

Comment: Your edited `null` check won't work if the `Control` from `FindControl` is not of type `CheckBox` it will throw an Exception.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, i don't think so.. please try in visual Studio.. :)

Comment: If `FindControl` returns `null`, not sure if that's possible, the check is fine. However, if it returns a different control, `Button` for example, the cast will throw an exception because a `Button` is not of type `CheckBox`.

Comment: it will type cast only if system gets the checkbox with that ID, otherwise it will return NULL.. it will not throw exception

Comment: What happens in your code if `FindControl` returns a `Button`?

Comment: it will return NULL in that case.. as no checkbox has that ID on the page..

Comment: No when `FindControl` returns a `Button`, your explicit cast will throw an `Exception`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142594/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-thelethalcoder).